# clearInterval not working in my angular code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When all files are finished running then the array `this.currentlyRunning` gets empty and its length is zero.

```
 if(numberOfFiles === 0) {
            clearInterval(this.repeat);
          }
```

I tested with console.log the if does get executed the if condition does evaluate to true still it doesn't clear the interval. If I console.log something there then then it keeps on outputting that value. If I put return statement there below clearInterval then only the below code doesnt execute but the timer keeps running until the return.

This only happens when more than one file are submitted for running, meaning that if currentlyRunning array has more than one objects. It happens only at the end when the array gets emptied

```
 export class ...... {
     repeat: any;   
     currentlyRunning = [];

OnInit(){......}

      checkFileStatus() {
        let index = 0;
        this.repeat = setInterval(() => {
          let numberOfFiles = this.currentlyRunning.length;
          if(numberOfFiles === 0) {
            clearInterval(this.repeat);
          }
        let file_id = {
          userFileId: this.currentlyRunning[index].id
        }
          this.auth.verifyProgress(file_id).subscribe((res: any)=>{
                if(res.userFileStatus === "Completed") {
                 ..........
                this.currentlyRunning.splice(index, 1);
                  });
                }
                index  = index + 1;
                  if(index >= numberOfFiles) {
                    index = 0;
                  }
                  if(this.currentlyRunning.length === 0) {
                    clearInterval(this.repeat);
                    return;
                }
             },(err)=>{ 
              index  = index + 1;
                if(index >= numberOfFiles) {
                  index = 0;
                }
                if(this.currentlyRunning.length === 0) {
                  clearInterval(this.repeat);
                  return;
               }
            });
        }, 4000);
        }

        }
```

Comment: Do you get any error in console? Also is this line clearInterval(this.repeat) inside if (numberOfFiles === 0) is hit?

Comment: no error if I put return inside the first if condition otherwise it tries to execute `userFileId: 'this.currentlyRunning[index].id'` and gives the error in console regarding the index coz the array is empty

Comment: Where / how do you populate the `currentlyRunning` array, can you share that part too?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your `auth.verifyProgress` has stack executions, and should be destroyed once it is completed.

Try this one, adding an `unsubscribe()`

`const listener = this.auth.verifyProgress(file_id).subscribe((res: any)=>{
            if(res.userFileStatus === "Completed") {
             ..........
            this.currentlyRunning.splice(index, 1);
              });
            }
            index  = index + 1;
              if(index >= numberOfFiles) {
                index = 0;
              }
              if(this.currentlyRunning.length === 0) {
                clearInterval(this.repeat);
                return;
            }
           listener.unsubscribe();
         }, (err)=>{ 
          index  = index + 1;
            if(index >= numberOfFiles) {
              index = 0;
            }
            if(this.currentlyRunning.length === 0) {
              clearInterval(this.repeat);
              return;
           }
           listener.unsubscribe();
        });`